# Including image in text file when generating XSL-fo file using docbook toolchain

Tags: xsl-fo, saxon, apache-fop, asciidoc

I am creating a pdf document using docbook tool chain. I follow the below format referring this link http://www.stevestreeting.com/2010/03/07/building-a-new-technical-documentation-tool-chain/

1] have a text file which includes all the content

2] convert this text file to xml file using asciidoc.py

3] use the generated xml file and with reference to docbook xsl files use saxon.jar to produce a .fo file

4] use the generated .fo file as an input to apache fop to generate a pdf file as the final result.

in the .fo file when I include < fo:external-graphic>  tag I am able to view the image in the pdf document.

```
<fo:block><fo:external-graphic width="auto" height="auto" content-width="36pt" src="url(images/artifact.PNG)"/></fo:block>
```

My requirement is I should not edit the .fo file, the generated .fo file should already have this  tag. Can anyone please give me some inputs on how I can edit my text file or any of the docbook xsl file parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AsciiDoc has separate macros for inline and block images.

- **inline**: `image:<target>[<attributes>]`.  See http://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc/asciidoc.css-embedded.html#X9
- **block**: `image::<target>[<attributes>]`.  Note the extra `:`.  See http://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc/asciidoc.css-embedded.html#X49